# Problem with TCPDF integrating in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, tcpdf

I'm getting a problem while running the TCPDF inside WordPress. I have uploaded the TCPDF entire folder in the /wp-content/plugins/TCPDF path. Set the permission to 0755. I wanted to access the tcpdf.php inside one of my custom plugins. In the code base, I wrote.

```
require_once(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/TCPDF/tcpdf.php'); 
//tested with the below code which is working fine means loading the file 

if (file_exists(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/TCPDF/tcpdf.php')) :
 echo WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/TCPDF/tcpdf.php';
  echo "Working..";
endif;
```

The rest of the code is simple to test a sample html.

```
$pdf = new TCPDF();
// Fetch website content
$html = '<body><h1>Hello World</h1></body>';

// Add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML($html);

// Output PDF
ob_clean();
ob_flush();
$pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');
ob_end_flush();
ob_end_clean();
exit;
```

This gives me a black screen while loading the HTML. I have tested the $pdf->writeHTML($html) which is not working. But the same is working in a simple .php page inside my local host without WordPress.

[image: This is the image while trying to run]

Can someone please help me how to debug or what might be the root cause? Maybe some autoload file is not working which is related to the path or something. please need a little help. Thanks.

Comment: Why the `ob_flush` etc.?